# How to make QWebEngineView of PyQt5 able to play audio?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qwebengineview

I want to play audio on the web use QWebEngineView of PyQt5. This is my code:

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWebEngineWidgets, QtWidgets

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

    view = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
    view.settings().setAttribute(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineSettings.PluginsEnabled, True)
    view.settings().setAttribute(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineSettings.JavascriptEnabled, True)

    html = '''
    <html>
        <audio id="pron" src="http://static.sfdict.com/staticrep/dictaudio/A06/A0612000.mp3"></audio>
        <button onclick="document.getElementById('pron').play()">Play!</button>
    </html>'''
    view.setHtml(html)

    view.resize(250, 150)
    view.move(300, 300)
    view.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

But when I click the `Play` button, the audio not play. What's wrong with me?

Comment: "Apple!" Works fine for me on linux. The settings make no difference. If you're on Windows, do you have all the necessary audio codecs installed? Try testing with a link to a wma file.

Comment: The same opinion as @ekhumoro

Comment: I got console warning when test your example , that is , js: Uncaught (in promise) NotSupportedError: The element has no supported sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[QWebEngineView doesn't support mp3 playback by default](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-features.html#audio-and-video-codecs) , at least on Win7 as I've tested . If you change your mp3 url to a ogg one(ogg format is supported by default through QWebEngineView ),   e.g.

```
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5a/Nl-URL%27s.ogg
```

then your example would work !

As I searched web, I found the only way to enable the mp3 playback is to compile our own Qt webengine, [someone told me the way to do it](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2018-June/040478.html) as following ,

> Compile your own Qt (including QtWebEngine), then compile PyQt and
>   when calling its configure.py, use --qmake to pass the path to the
>   correct qmake executable.

If anyone interests in compiling Qt webengine, these information may be helpful

[How to compile Qt webengine (5.11) on Windows with proprietary codecs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50510457/how-to-compile-qt-webengine-5-11-on-windows-with-proprietary-codecs/)

[Unable to get mp3 support with QtWebEngine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41611445/unable-to-get-mp3-support-with-qtwebengine)