# Build QtWebEngine 5.9.1 with proprietary codecs

Tags: qt, visual-c++, qtwebengine, qt5.9

We need to support to mp4 file in QtwebengineView. So we are trying to build qtwebengine of Qt 5.9.1 on msvc2015 x64, with proprietary codecs, by using following  command at cmd with working directory is qtwebengine in source.

```
"D:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.9.1\qtbase\bin\qmake.exe WEBENGINE_CONFIG+=use_proprietary_codecs"
```

we are facing below error.

```
WinRT is not supported.
QtWebEngine will not be built
```

We tried to follow following link:
[How to compile Qt webengine (5.11) on Windows with proprietary codecs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50510457/how-to-compile-qt-webengine-5-11-on-windows-with-proprietary-codecs)
But that didn't work either.

How can we build qtwebengine of qt 5.9.1 with proprietary codecs?

Comment: read: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-deploying.html#target-platforms, It clearly states that WinRT does not support QtWebEngine: *On Windows, Qt WebEngine only supports Windows Vista or newer as target platform. Due to use of newer API in Chromium, Windows XP is not supported. WinRT is not supported, either*, so you can not use it.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but we are using Qt-5.9.1 which is not of uwp. Our's is the windows desktop application without uwp support. Still we are getting WinRT is not supported error.

Comment: similar in Qt 5.9: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.9/qtwebengine-deploying.html

Answer (score 1):

I just successfully build QtWebEngine 5.9.6

My build environment:

- Windows7 x64
- Visual Studio 2015 x64
- jom 1.1.2

You can refer to my build process.

Before we start building, let's install the tools:

- Python 2.7.13 from https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/
- Perl (Strawberry vesion) from http://strawberryperl.com/
- Bison and flex from https://sourceforge.net/projects/winflexbison/ (Rename win-bison.exe to bison.exe and win-flex.exe to flex.exe)
- Gperf from http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gperf.htm

Download the source code for qt

```
git clone https://code.qt.io/qt/qt5.git
cd qt5
git checkout 5.9.6
perl init-repository --module-subset=qtwebengine,qtwebview
```

Let's start the formal build

```
cd qtwebengine
qmake.exe WEBENGINE_CONFIG+=use_proprietary_codecs
jom.exe
```

Then there's the long build process...

The final file will be generated in the qt5/qtwebengine/bin directory after the build is completed

Comment: Thanks, will try this.

Comment: I followed these steps, at the qmake step, I got: `bison...yes, python2... [shows file path], gperf...yes, flex... yes, submodule initialized... no. Project ERROR: Unknown feature object private_tests in expression 'features.private_tests'.` Do you have any idea what is causing this problem? I am constantly removing the .cache, .stash and .super files before rebuilding. In the config.log file: `executing config test webengine-submodule
test config.qtwebengine_buildtools.tests.webengine-submodule FAILED`