# qmake.exe not found Installing QtWebEngine with proprietary codecs

Tags: qt, qmake, qtwebengine

I am trying to build qtwebengine with proprietary codecs. I am following the answer on this stack overflow questions: [Build QtWebEngine 5.9.1 with proprietary codecs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52099150/build-qtwebengine-5-9-1-with-proprietary-codecs). I have installed all the specified programs and began trying to build it. I made it to the `git checkout 5.9.6` line before I had my first error. I fixed this by changing it to `git checkout 5.9.8` and it seemed to work, so I then continued, however now it has given me another error that qmake.exe isn't recognized. I have looked everywhere in the qt folder and can't find any sign of the file. What have I done wrong to mean this has happened, could it be me changing the line to `git checkout 5.9.8` or I haven't installed something correctly?

Comment: You must have qt installed to get qmake.exe

Comment: @eyllanesc As in installed as a python library?

Comment: No, you have to use the Qt online installer. It seems that you have never worked with Qt so I presume that you are going to have more problems.